# current page refresh problem in framework7

Tags: caching, routes, html-framework-7

Framework7 version: Framework7 3.1.1

I am using component template

I tried solutions but current page is not refresh

Solution 1:

```
app.on('pageInit', function (page) {
  if (page.name === 'single-question') { 
  var mainView = app.view.create('#single-page');
  mainView.router.refreshPage(); 
}
```

when I console page name and click to open single-page it returns “null” and then app is not working without refresh.

Solution: 2

```
router.navigate(router.currentRoute.url, {
  reloadCurrent: true,
  ignoreCache: true,
});
```

But I got error: “Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: currentRoute is not defined”

I aslo try

```
Cache:false,
cacheDuration: 0,
template7Pages = false
```

but still facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to refresh page by this:

```
self.app.router.navigate(app.views.main.router.url, {reloadCurrent: true});
```

Comment: Its not working for me still facing same problem @AnisHikmatAbu-Hmiad

Comment: mm, Maybe there's another issue, since this one I work for me in my project, what about page layout? its like this: <div class="view">
    <!-- Initial Page, "data-name" contains page name -->
    <div data-name="pageName" class="page">.......etc

Answer (score -1):

You can refresh the whole page using this

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000);
```